# Formatting time4j moment

Tags: java, leap-second, time4j

For one of the projects, I was given a millisecond from another system. 
I need to convert to "**yyyy-DDDT:HH:mm:ssZ**"

The trick is to display it in **leap-second**.

Since Java libraries does not have leap-second, I decided to use **Time4J**'s **Moment** class.

But **Moment**'s `toString()` is printing `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`.

Is it possible to get **day of year** in Moment class?

Is there any example to create a custom formatter. I tried a few including `ChronoFormatter`. but could not get the desired results.

One nasty workaround is to use `Calendar` for **Date** part and `Moment` for **time** part.

But it is tedious, and will be difficult when parsing back from String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting or parsing moments/instants with the element day-of-year is no special problem with the class `Moment` and can be done just by choosing a [suitable pattern](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/PatternType.html#CLDR), see this demonstration for a leap second:

```
Moment ls = PlainTimestamp.of(2016, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59).atUTC().plus(1, SI.SECONDS);
System.out.println(ls); // 2016-12-31T23:59:60Z
ChronoFormatter<Moment> f =
    ChronoFormatter.ofMomentPattern(
        "uuuu-DDD'T'HH:mm:ssX", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT, ZonalOffset.UTC);
String text = f.format(ls);
System.out.println(text); // 2016-366T23:59:60Z
Moment parsed = f.parse(text);
System.out.println(parsed.isSimultaneous(ls)); // true
```

Keep in mind that any [conversion](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/TemporalType.html#INSTANT) of `Moment`-objects to for example `java.time.Instant` or `java.util.Date` will loose the leap second info however.

Another point: Getting access to the day-of-year-element in class `Moment` is not directly possible because the day-of-year is a local element not related to the universal time without zone offset but can be done programmatically if you also specify a zone offset or a timezone. Example:

```
System.out.println(ls.get(PlainDate.DAY_OF_YEAR.at(ZonalOffset.UTC))); // 366
```

The same procedure can also be applied to time elements:

```
System.out.println(ls.get(PlainTime.SECOND_OF_MINUTE.at(ZonalOffset.UTC))); // 60
```

About the last example: It will only work in context of `Moment` but not in context of the local type `PlainTime`, of course. The leap second support is deeply embedded in Time4J on all levels when handling the class `Moment`, programmatically and in formatting and parsing.

Comment: Thank you so much!.